# Reorganizing ASP.NET MVC Folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to migrate web forms app to mvc. One of the organizational issues I would need to tackle is  our folder structure.  Currenly it's organized by functional area e.g.

- Application

  - Functional Area (e.g. MyAccount)

    - Task 1 (Manage Notifications)
    - Task 2 (Change Payment Info)
    - etc..
  - Functional Area

    - Task 1
    - Task 2
    - etc..

which works quite nicely for our task-based app. However, from my understanding, the default organization with an MVC app is similiar to

- Controllers

  - Task1Controller.cs
  - Task2Controller.cs
- Views

  - Task 1

    - ViewOne.aspx
    - ViewTwo.aspx
  - Task 2

    - ViewOne.aspx
- Models

etc.....

I would like to retain the layout we currently have.  I'm envisioning a structure more like

- Application

  - Functional Area (My Account)

    - Task 1

      - Controller
      - View 1
      - View 2
    - Task 2

      - Controller
      - View 1
      - View 2

etc...

Which roads do I need to head down to achieve this? And if I did, what kind of pain would I suffer from deviating quite drastically from the convention?

Answer (score 4):

This is something that's available in version **2.0** of ASP.NET MVC.

They're calling it [**Areas**](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx)

[Some more info from Phil Haack.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx)

[Here's what Steve Sanderson has said.](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/)

These areas are designed to allow you to seperate out your models, views and controllers into logical "areas".

- Area1

  - Model
  - View
  - Controller
- Area2

  - Model
  - View
  - Controller

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[areas](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx)** in ASP.NET MVC 2.0.